# Sybase ASE + .NetCore (+ Dapper) Exception: request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected ... no address

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, ado.net, database-connection, sybase

I'm calling sybase ase via Dapper with parameterized sql in .NetCore 2, using AdoDotNetCore.AdoClient.Using it to hit a sybase DB.

I keep getting the "A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied." error

but the error seems to mean "something went wrong" Its been bad data types on return object, connection timeouts etc.

I'm spending a ton of time trying to brute force debug these errors. Is there a better way to debug these to get to the root issue?

example working code:

```
var aseSqlConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("SybaseDBDapper");
            
            StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();

            query.Append("SELECT stud_id, ad_guid, ad_name, ad_pass_expire_dt, ad_last_login_dt, alumni");
            query.Append("      from student  ");
            query.Append("  where LOWER( ad_name ) = Lower( @studentAdName )   ");

            string sql = query.ToString();

            DapperTools.DapperCustomMapping< StudentAdDataResponse >( );

            try
            {
                using ( IDbConnection db = new AseConnection(aseSqlConnectionString) )
                {
                    var arguments = new
                                        {
                                            studentAdName = sAdName,
                                        };

                    List< StudentAdDataResponse > ll = new List< StudentAdDataResponse >();
                    //StudentAdDataResponse res =  db.QueryFirst<StudentAdDataResponse>(sql, arguments);
                    //ll.Add( res );

                    ll = db.Query<StudentAdDataResponse>(sql, arguments).ToList();
                    return ll;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine( ex.ToString(  ) );
                return null;
            }
```

example bad code

```
string sql        = " SELECT period.period_day_cd,    " +
                                "           period.period_no,    " +
                                "           period.period_start_tm,    " +
                                "           period.period_end_tm,    " +
                                "           classroom.clsrm_loc_cd,    " +
                                "           classroom.clsrm_no,    " +
                                "           course.course_name,    " +
                                "           student_schedule.stud_sched_eff_dt,    " +
                                "           student_schedule.sched_type_cd,    " +
                                "           code.code_desc,    " +
                                "           staff.staff_lname,    " +
                                "           staff.staff_fname,    " +
                                "           staff.staff_mi, " +
                                "           'N' as first_eff_dt" +
                                "      FROM code,    " +
                                "           classroom,    " +
                                "           course,    " +
                                "           period,    " +
                                "           staff,    " +
                                "           student_schedule,    " +
                                "           class,    " +
                                "           class_period,    " +
                                "           schedule_item,    " +
                                "           stud_class_sched   " +
                                "     WHERE ( student_schedule.sched_type_cd  = code.code_id ) and   " +
                                "           ( class.clsrm_id = classroom.clsrm_id ) and   " +
                                "           ( schedule_item.sched_item_id = course.sched_item_id ) and   " +
                                "           ( student_schedule.stud_sched_id = stud_class_sched.stud_sched_id ) and   " +
                                "           ( class_period.cls_period_id = stud_class_sched.cls_period_id ) and   " +
                                "           ( class_period.period_id = period.period_id ) and   " +
                                "           ( class_period.cls_id = class.cls_id ) and   " +
                                "           ( class.staff_id = staff.staff_id ) and   " +
                                "           ( class.sched_item_id = schedule_item.sched_item_id ) and   " +
                                "           ( student_schedule.enrtype_id = @enrtypeid ) " +
                                "           order by student_schedule.stud_sched_eff_dt desc,   " +
                                "                   code.code_desc,   " +
                                "                   period.period_day_cd, " +
                                "                   period.period_start_tm  ";


            var aseSqlConnectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("SybaseDBDapper");
            dapperTools.DapperCustomMapping<StdInfoScheduleCV>();

            try
            {
                List<StdInfoScheduleCV> ll = new List<StdInfoScheduleCV>();

                using ( IDbConnection db = new AseConnection( aseSqlConnectionString ) )
                {
                    try
                    {
                        db.Open(    );


                        var arguments = new
                                            {
                                                enrtypeid = EnrTypeId,
                                            };

                        ll = jcdcDbQuery< StdInfoScheduleCV >( db, sql, arguments );
                    }
                    catch ( Exception ex )
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        db.Close();
                    }

                    return ll;
                }
            }
            catch ( Exception ex )
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                //return new List< StdInfoScheduleCV >();
                throw;
            }
```

I've tried everything I can think of, but can't find the issue.

What steps can I take to diagnose the Sybase ASE + Dapper issue.

The non working code was ported over from a working asp.net mvc 4.5 app, and the db code converted to dapper and .netcore

Comment: I guess this has nothing to do with `Dapper`, executing the query/command directly (e.g: using ADO.NET) would fail with that same exception. It's almost something wrong with the connection string or the target it points to. Have you tried testing the connection first yourself? Even using some external tool should be tried out.

Comment: I have other SQL wrappers methods that call the same DB with the same Connection string and it works perfectly. The code is extreemly similar *(different sql and parameters, that's it)

Comment: It was not Dapper, it was Sybase, I changed all the int64s in the code to int32s and Sybase was happy, the ASE driver has some kind of issue with int64s

Comment: so that `Sybase` was not even tagged. Also what you asked does not provide any info related to how you solved it and what you fixed. It would be nice if you update your question with more detail and a correct tag before posting your own answer which should be related to the question. All the users visiting this will see a clear relation between the question (issue) and the answer (solution to the issue) and that will probably help them as well as teach them something new.

Comment: is that Better?

Comment: to me, it's still unclear on what you changed from `int64` to `int32`.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out that the Sybase driver, had issues with int64s.

In my query objects (in and out) I changed all the int64s to int32s, and Sybase was was happy and the error went away.

P.S. I have also gotten the same error for sending "DateTime.ToString()" in as a date, you need to send it as a short date string "DateTime.ToShortDateString()".