# using aseconnection and sybase12 error tryng to do an insert but not fails when i use a select

Tags: c#, .net, sybase

I am using *sybase 12 and .net*, in the repository I have everything that is called to the database with select/ or the get method works bine but what are update/insert (that is, post and put) do not work and give the error

> "A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied."*...

My question or what I don't understand is if for the `SELECT` works but for an `INSERT` it does not, so it is not a problem with the code or with .net... and the base is not turned off (the error says that a socket in the base is turned off and that is why it cannot do the insert) but it can doing a select should be able to do an update... does anyone know what it could be?

This is the example, and fail before the line

> await conexion.ExecuteAsync(sqlInserts, parametrosInserts);

```
public async Task<bool> RenaperUpdateEstadoFallecidosBorrados(string dni, string fecha)
{
    try
    {
        using (var conexion = _conexionSybase)
        {
            await conexion.OpenAsync();
            using (var transaction = conexion.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    var sqlSelect = @"SELECT * FROM beneficiarios_renaper WHERE dni = convert(INT, @dni)";
                    var parametrosSelect = new { @dni = dni };
                    var beneficiario = await conexion.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<DtoDeRenaper>(sqlSelect, parametrosSelect);
                    if (beneficiario != null)
                    {
                        beneficiario.estado = "B";
                        var sqlUpdate = @"UPDATE beneficiarios_renaper SET estado = @estado, fecha_estado = @fecha_estado WHERE dni = convert(int,@dni)";
                        var parametrosUpdate = new
                        {
                            @estado = beneficiario.estado,
                            @fecha_estado = DateTime.Now,
                            @dni = beneficiario.dni
                        };
                        // Actualizar el estado del beneficiario
                        await conexion.ExecuteAsync(sqlUpdate, parametrosUpdate);
                        var mensaje = "registro actualizado, estado B!";
                        var sqlInsert = @"INSERT INTO seguimiento
                    (dni, sexo, fecha_alta, estado_mensaje, mensaje)
                    VALUES (@dni, @sexo, @fecha_alta, @estado_mensaje, @mensaje)";
                        var parametrosInsert = new
                        {
                            @dni = beneficiario.dni,
                            @sexo = beneficiario.sexo,
                            @fecha_alta = DateTime.Now,
                            @estado_mensaje = 2,
                            @mensaje = mensaje
                        };
                        // Registrar el seguimiento
                        await conexion.ExecuteAsync(sqlInsert, parametrosInsert);
                        var mensajeDos = "fecha Grabada con exito para Aviso";
                        var sqlInserts = @"INSERT INTO seguimiento
                    (dni, sexo, fecha_alta, estado_mensaje, mensaje)
                    VALUES (@dni, @sexo, @fecha_alta, @estado_mensaje, @mensaje)";
                        var parametrosInserts = new
                        {
                            @dni = 99999999,
                            @sexo = beneficiario.sexo,
                            @fecha_alta = fecha,
                            @estado_mensaje = 4,
                            @mensaje = mensajeDos
                        };
                        // Registrar el seguimiento
                        await conexion.ExecuteAsync(sqlInserts, parametrosInserts);
                        transaction.Commit(); // Se confirman los cambios en la base de datos
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback(); // Se revierten los cambios en caso de error
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
                    // Manejar la excepción según tus necesidades
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error de conexión: " + ex.Message);
        // Manejar la excepción según tus necesidades
        return false;
    }
}
```

The only post I found with a similar error is this one --> [Sybase ASE + .NetCore (+ Dapper) Exception: request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected ... no address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65585977/sybase-ase-netcore-dapper-exception-request-to-send-or-receive-data-was)  but it doesn't give much information and the issue of int64/int32 doesn't seem to be the problem since I use int and not long